# Unable to create alias having pipe

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I want to make an alias `tree` with `find ./ -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'` as its value.

so to avoid mistakes due to `'` inside whole line I converted them to `\'` by which I can define it's scope.
so my actual command looks like this:

```
alias tree='find ./ -type d -print | sed -e \'s;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g\''
```

but it shows error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

but I don't know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer I tried some random hits and the solution is...

```
alias tree="find ./ -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'"
```

By using double quotes `"` .